# How to set up Visual Studio 2022 (Community) properly to launch and debug FastAPI apps?

Tags: python, visual-studio, fastapi, visual-studio-2022

First time posting here.

Long story short: I am unable to properly tweak the pyproj starting file of VS 2022 so it can launch a FastAPI project out of the box.

Since there is no template laying around for this, I was wondering whether someone has a working .pyproj starting file that is compatible with FastAPI.

I know there are other options as to launch a project (via CLI) but the idea here is to have the starting script always be right for every new FastAPI project I create.

Doing a little experimenting I tried to grab a Django pyproj and adapt it, with the commands swapped with uvicorn. Still, no luck.

[django pyproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM9Mr.png)

I appreciate any help!